# How to make X values with corresponding small Y values more visible in a histogram

Tags: r, plotly

I was wondering if there is a way to  make X values with corresponding small Y values more visible in a plotly histogram.

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(50000), type = "histogram")
p
```

[image]

For exampe in the image above there are oviously some x values near -4 and 4 that have very small `y` values in comparison with 1000 which seems to be the biggest `y` value. I know that this is relative but could the tiny values be displayed with bigger and more visible bars?

Comment: Not on the same axis. If you create bigger bars you are changing the Y value, which would be incorrect. You could possibly make them more visible, but it would have to be superficial, something like a color gradient? You could also add value labels, or allow for zoom.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good idea to change height of the bars. Instead you can try something like this:

```
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5000), y = -1)

p <- plot_ly(data = df, x = x, type = "histogram") 

add_markers(p, 
            data = df,
            x = ~x,
            y = ~y,
            type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'markers',
            marker = list(symbol = 'star', size = ~abs(x), color = 'green', alpha = 0.5, line = list(color = 'transparent')))
```

[image]

Now it is possible to see that you have some observations close to 4 for example.